# List of database elements with radio_button form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, flash, radio-button

I am trying to build a multiple choice exam web app such that you can retrieve a bunch of questions based on search criteria and then answer the questions and get feedback on whether you answered correctly or not.

My questions_controller has the following method:

```
def check_answer
  @question = Question.find(params[:id])
  if params[:response] == @question.answer
    @outcome = 'correct'
  else 
    @outcome = 'incorrect'
  end  
    flash[:notice] = "That is #{@outcome}."
    redirect_to :back
```

where the layout index is :

```
<% @questions.each do |question| %>
    <h4> <%= question.stem %></h4>
    <%= form_tag "/check_answer/#{question.id}", :method => 'get' do%>
    <%= radio_button_tag "response", "a" %> <%= question.option_a%>
        <%= radio_button_tag "response", "b" %> <%= question.option_b%>
    <%= radio_button_tag "response", "c" %> <%= question.option_c%>
    <%= radio_button_tag "response", "d" %> <%= question.option_d%>
    <%= radio_button_tag "response", "e" %> <%= question.option_e%>     
    <%= submit_tag "Check Answer" %>
<% end %>

<% if flash[:notice] %>
<div class = "notice"><%= flash[:notice] %></div>
<% end %>
```

However when I select one of the radio buttons it returns "that is (in)correct" at the bottom of EVERY question. That makes sense based on the code I just don't know how I would change it so it only displays "that is correct" at the bottom of the 1 question on which you click the "check answer" box.

Answer (score 0):

By your questions, try adding a piece of logic to annotate the outcome.

View:

```
<% @correct_field ||= nil %>
<% @questions.each do |question| %>
  <h4> <%= question.stem %></h4>
    <%= form_tag "/check_answer/#{question.id}", :method => 'get' do%>
      <%= radio_button_tag "response", "a" %> <%= question.option_a%><% "CORRECT!" if @correct_field == "a" %>
      <%= radio_button_tag "response", "b" %> <%= question.option_b%><% "CORRECT!" if @correct_field == "b" %>
      <%= radio_button_tag "response", "c" %> <%= question.option_c%><% "CORRECT!" if @correct_field == "c" %>
      <%= radio_button_tag "response", "d" %> <%= question.option_d%><% "CORRECT!" if @correct_field == "d" %>
      <%= radio_button_tag "response", "e" %> <%= question.option_e%><% "CORRECT!" if @correct_field == "e" %>     
     <%= submit_tag "Check Answer" %>
    <% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def check_answer
  @question = Question.find(params[:id])
  if params[:response] == @question.answer
    @correct_field = @params[:response]
    @outcome = 'correct'
  else 
    @outcome = 'incorrect'
  end  
  flash[:notice] = "That is #{@outcome}."
  redirect_to :back
```

In the controller, just set @correct_field to whichever of the `params` resolves to the string representing the choice, as above.

That said, I'd not do it this way. It feels sort of more like a problem that should be solved using partials and/or JavaScript and AJAX calls. Hope that helps anyway.